# coc-nvim empty actions, implementation and type definition provider not found

Tags: vim, coc.nvim

I have `coc.nvim` with `pyright` and `vetur` installed. I have the following in my `.vimrc`

```
nmap <silent> gd <Plug>(coc-definition)
nmap <silent> gy <Plug>(coc-type-definition)
nmap <silent> gi <Plug>(coc-implementation)
nmap <silent> gr <Plug>(coc-references)
```

I was hoping that pressnig `gi` over a function name will take me to the implementation, but alas, neither that nor `gy` does anything. This is the output of `:CocInfo:`

```
undefined## versions

vim version: VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 8012269
node version: v14.15.0
coc.nvim version: 0.0.79-8b967b0bbd
coc.nvim directory: /home/fbence/.vim/plugged/coc.nvim
term: dumb
platform: linux

## Log of coc.nvim

2020-12-12T18:33:40.895 INFO (pid:131785) [services] - registered service "pyright"
2020-12-12T18:33:40.896 INFO (pid:131785) [services] - Pyright Server state change: stopped => starting
2020-12-12T18:33:40.945 INFO (pid:131785) [plugin] - coc.nvim 0.0.79-8b967b0bbd initialized with node: v14.15.0 after 146ms
2020-12-12T18:33:40.952 INFO (pid:131785) [language-client-index] - pyright started with 131932
2020-12-12T18:33:41.096 INFO (pid:131785) [services] - Pyright Server state change: starting => running
2020-12-12T18:33:41.100 INFO (pid:131785) [services] - service pyright started
2020-12-12T18:33:42.654 INFO (pid:131785) [completion-complete] - Results from: around,pyright-1
2020-12-12T18:33:45.820 INFO (pid:131785) [completion-complete] - Results from: around,pyright-1
2020-12-12T18:34:48.147 WARN (pid:131785) [Handler] - type definition provider not found!
2020-12-12T18:34:55.149 WARN (pid:131785) [Handler] - implementation provider not found!
```

Output in a `vue` file with `vetur` is similiar, I get type definition provider not found, implementation provider not found. I also find it strange that checking `:CocList actions` returns empty. Is something not set up properly or are these functionalities not provided by the two language servers I happen to be using? If so, are there better servers?

Comment: Does `gd` `gr` work for you with coc-pyright?

Comment: Yes, both of them do.